# PHP system() not working on Laravel Forge

Tags: php, laravel, server, zip

Locally, I have a class created that creates zip files with no issues.

When pushed up to the server however it is having issues. Its a Laravel Spark app, on Laravel Forge servers.

I've tried to debug normally returning the system() method gives some response, on the server I get nothing output when retuning this method.

The issue is that i'm calling a response download method for the zip file that should have been created. However I am getting file not found and I can only link it to the system() method.

Heres the code i'm using to create the zip:

```
 echo system('zip -j -P ' .$this->password. ' ' .$this->getZipStoragePath(). ' ' .storage_path('app/').$this->getFilePath());
```

Is there any chance that the server might not allow me to use the system method? Its all I can debug it to right now?

Comment: could you try to see if you get any errors? (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php#66795) and maybe check this issue too (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php#40454)

Answer (score 1):

You most probably get an error from the function. To capture it, run the function with the stream redirection operator `2>&1` appended to your command:

```
$output = system('zip -j -P ' . $this->password . ' ' . $this->getZipStoragePath() . ' ' . storage_path('app/') . $this->getFilePath() . ' 2>&1');

var_dump($output);
```

It could also be worth to check out whether the function is enabled at all on your server.

In your `php.ini` file, look for the `disable_functions` directive. It might look like this:

```
disable_functions=show_source, system, shell_exec
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @silkfire I've updated the method as suggested at get this error: 'sh: 1: zip: not found'. Also checked the disabled functions but no mention of the system method.

Comment: I've got it figured out now. Will post an answer.

Comment: @Lovelock Great. Please upvote my answer if it helped you to discover the culprit to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this one by trying to run 'zip' on the server but received:

```
The program 'zip' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt install zip
```

Running this allowed the zip feature to work.